# Check that all rows in table A have a specific value in table B, including a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - *students* and *evidence* - and I'm trying to check for a corresponding value in one column in *evidence*, grouped by another column in *evidence* for every entry in *students*

These are what the tables look like:

```
> desc students;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname  | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| surname    | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| class_id   | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dob        | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enrollment | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

> desc evidence;
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned                            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type          | enum('written','image','audio','video','link') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mime          | varchar(191)                                   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| path          | varchar(191)                                   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | int(11)                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_recorded | datetime                                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| statement_id  | int(11)                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| progress      | int(11)                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notes         | mediumtext                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student       | int(11)                                        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | timestamp                                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | timestamp                                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Entries in the *evidence* table are associated with a student (evidence.student_id) and an evidence statement (evidence.statement_id) and then given a *progress* value of 1 (in progress) or 2 (complete).

I want to be able to check that for each *statement_id* every student has at least one row with the *progress* entry set to 2. Ideally I'd like to GROUP BY statement_id and only return a value of 2 for *progress* if every student has at least one row in the evidence table for that *statement_id* where *progress* has been set to 2.

The goal is to list all of the *statement_id*s where everyone in a class has completed the task (and therefore had some evidence added with *progress* set to complete).

I've tried doing joins similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM students left join evidence ON students.id = evidence.student GROUP BY evidence.statement_id HAVING progress = 2;
```

but the problem there is that if one student is marked as completing a *statement_id* but another student doesn't have any entries for that *statement_id* then *progress* will return 2. I'd rather it just returned NULL for the student without any entries.

I'm pretty stumped on this one to any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You say you want records per student, then you say you want to use group by. You can do one or the other, but you need two separate queries to do both (those queries can be combined into a single resultset with union).

Comment: My question might have been a bit wordy. I basically just want to say whether all students have an entry in *evidence* where progress = 2 for each *statement_id*.

Comment: Again, do you want a list or do you want a summary, or do you just want a yes / no per statement id. Also, do you need to check against the complete list of statements or is it enough to work with the statement ids in the evidence table?

Comment: A yes/no per statement_id should do the trick. A full list of every statement id isn't necessary, just a list of the statement ids where every student has a 2 for progress in there somewhere.